# How do I place a content under a position:absolute?

Tags: html, css

I'm still not too familiar with CSS, still working on it and learning through YouTube for the design purpose.

The sticky navigation bar will only stick on bottom IF its position: absolute. And here comes the problem: How do I put my content next to the navigation bar? Foremost the content that I put beneath it won't let the page expand more space/ letting me to scroll anyway.

I've tried to figure this out by adjusting everything like position, float, etc, and I'm still stuck. Forgive me for my ignorance, and thanks for the help.

```css
/* Background slider */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas-Neue';
  src: url('BebasNeue.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}

.slide-1,.slide-2,.slide-3 {
 position:absolute;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:1;
 background-attachment:fixed;
}

.slider .line {
 position: absolute;
 width: 98%;
 height: auto;
 bottom: 40%;
 margin: 10px;
 z-index:999;
}

.slider .slider-caption {
   font-family:Oswald;
 height: 0%;
 bottom:25%;
 left:16px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-size:50px;
 min-height: 80px;
 position: absolute; 
 font-weight:bold;
 z-index:999;
}

.slider .slider-description {
   font-family:Oswald;
 bottom:20%;
 left:16px;
 font-size:15px;
 height:0%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index:999;
}

.slide-1 {
 background-image:url('../image/01_contentslider_1.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 animation: fade-1 12s infinite;
 -webkit-animation: fade-1 12s infinite;
}

.slide-2 {
 background-image:url('../image/01_contentslider_2.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 animation: fade-2 12s infinite;
 -webkit-animation: fade-2 12s infinite;
}

.slide-3 {
 background-image:url('../image/01_contentslider_3.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 animation: fade-3 12s infinite;
 -webkit-animation: fade-3 12s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-1 {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 25% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@keyframes fade-1 {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 25% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-2 {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 25% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@keyframes fade-2 {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 25% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-3 {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 25% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

@keyframes fade-3 {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 25% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 75% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

.transparency { /*Opacity 50*/
    position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background:url('../image/00_Transparent.png');
 top: 0;
 bottom:0;
    z-index: -1000;
 overflow:hidden;
}

/* Sticky Nav Bar Settings */

.content-layer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom:0;
 float:left;
 padding:0;
}

#nav-bar {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   bottom:0;
   z-index:999;
}

#nav-bar a {
   float: left;
   display: block;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
}

#nav-bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    margin-left: 350px;
}

#nav-bar li {
    float: left; 
}

#nav-bar a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
}

#nav-bar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Arial";
    color: #4c4c4c;
    border-right: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
}

#nav-bar a.active {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
}

.page-content {
   padding: 16px;
   z-index: 999;
 bottom: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
}

.sticky {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .page-content {
   padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Home | Reise Web-Portal </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/00_Fundamentals.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/02_Parallax_Slider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/00_Loading....css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/00_Bebas_Neue_Font.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <!-- Loading Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      $('.preloader').addClass('complete')
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Loading the Page OP -->
  <div class="preloader">
    <div class="loader">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Loading the Page ED -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Appearance of all content     
    $(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.showcase').removeClass('hidden');
      }, 4500);
    })();
  </script>
  <div class="page">
    <span class="menu-toggle">
  <i class="menu-open fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
  <i class="menu-close fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
 </span>

    <ul class="menu-items">
      <img class="menu-logo-pic" alt="Reise Web-Portal" src="image/00_Logo_2.png">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Stuff inside the page -->
    <div class="content">
      <!-- Home Page -->
      <div class="background-slide">
        <!-- Slide Show -->
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slide-1">
            <div class="transparency">
              <div class="line">
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-caption">
                <h4>Start Your Journey</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-description">
                <h2>Now or never.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-2">
            <div class="transparency">
              <div class="line">
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-caption">
                <h4>Enjoy your life without regrets</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-description">
                <h2>By understanding the world in a greater depth.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-3">
            <div class="transparency">
              <div class="line">
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-caption">
                <h4>Reach the sky with your hands</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-description">
                <h2>Fuck this shit.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="page-content">
        <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
        <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Sticky Nav Bar Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Off Canvas Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var $page = $('.page');

    $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
      $page.toggleClass('shazam');
    });

    $('.content').on('click', function() {
      $page.removeClass('shazam');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
/*02_Parallax_Slider.css*/


/* Background slider */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas-Neue';
  src: url('BebasNeue.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}

.slide-1,
.slide-2,
.slide-3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.slider .line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 40%;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.slider .slider-caption {
  font-family: Oswald;
  height: 0%;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  min-height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 999;
}

.slider .slider-description {
  font-family: Oswald;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}

.slide-1 {
  background-image: url('../image/01_contentslider_1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade-1 12s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade-1 12s infinite;
}

.slide-2 {
  background-image: url('../image/01_contentslider_2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade-2 12s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade-2 12s infinite;
}

.slide-3 {
  background-image: url('../image/01_contentslider_3.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: fade-3 12s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: fade-3 12s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.transparency {
  /*Opacity 50*/
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('../image/00_Transparent.png');
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Sticky Nav Bar Settings */

.content-layer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}

#nav-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

#nav-bar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#nav-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

#nav-bar li {
  float: left;
}

#nav-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#nav-bar li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: #4c4c4c;
  border-right: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
}

#nav-bar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.page-content {
  padding: 16px;
  z-index: 999;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.page-content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/* 00_Fundamentals.CSS */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
}

body {
  color: white;
}

.page {
  height: 200%;
  background-color: #000;
}

.content {
  height: 50%;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(1, 0.005, 0.24, 1), -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(1, 0.005, 0.24, 1);
}

.content-inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu-toggle {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
}

.menu-toggle:active i {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.menu-toggle i {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.menu-toggle .menu-open,
.menu-toggle .menu-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: : -12px;
  transition: transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(1, 0.005, 0.25, 1), -webkit-transform 0.7s cubic-bezier(1, 0.005, 0.25, 1);
}

.menu-toggle .menu-open {
  transform-origin: -100px -100px;
}

.menu-toggle .menu-close {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  transform-origin: -100px -160px;
}

.menu-items {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-items li {
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transform: translateX(-300px);
  transition: transform 0.7s 0s cubic-bezier(1, 0.005, 0.24, 1), -webkit-transform 0.7s 0s cubic-bezier(1, 0.005, 0.24, 1);
}

.menu-items li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.menu-items li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.menu-items li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: 160px;
}

.menu-items a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: color .2s;
}

.menu-items a:hover {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}


/* the class to Open the menu */

.shazam .content {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.shazam .menu-open {
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.shazam .menu-close {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.shazam .menu-items li {
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.35s 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275), -webkit-transform 0.35s 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.shazam .menu-items li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: .47s;
}

.shazam .menu-items li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: .48s;
}

h1 {
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.menu-logo-pic {
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .6s;
  left: -90px;
}

.shazam .menu-items .menu-logo-pic {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .6s;
}


/* Footer */

.center {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.bg-light {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #333;
}

.bg-dark {
  background: #333;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

footer {
  padding: 2.2rem;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
}

.newone {
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 840px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Home | Reise Web-Portal </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/00_Fundamentals.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/02_Parallax_Slider.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/00_Loading....css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/00_Bebas_Neue_Font.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <!-- Loading Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      $('.preloader').addClass('complete')
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Loading the Page OP -->
  <div class="preloader">
    <div class="loader">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Loading the Page ED -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Appearance of all content     
    $(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.showcase').removeClass('hidden');
      }, 4500);
    })();
  </script>
  <div class="page">
    <span class="menu-toggle">
  <i class="menu-open fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
  <i class="menu-close fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
 </span>

    <ul class="menu-items">
      <img class="menu-logo-pic" alt="Reise Web-Portal" src="image/00_Logo_2.png">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Stuff inside the page -->
    <div class="content">
      <!-- Home Page -->
      <div class="background-slide">
        <!-- Slide Show -->
        <div class="slider">
          <div class="slide-1">
            <div class="transparency">
              <div class="line">
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-caption">
                <h4>Start Your Journey</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-description">
                <h2>Now or never.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-2">
            <div class="transparency">
              <div class="line">
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-caption">
                <h4>Enjoy your life without regrets</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-description">
                <h2>By understanding the world in a greater depth.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide-3">
            <div class="transparency">
              <div class="line">
                <hr>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-caption">
                <h4>Reach the sky with your hands</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="slider-description">
                <h2>Fuck this shit.</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="page-content">
        <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
        <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Sticky Nav Bar Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    var navbar = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
  </script>

  <!-- Off Canvas Script -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var $page = $('.page');

    $('.menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
      $page.toggleClass('shazam');
    });

    $('.content').on('click', function() {
      $page.removeClass('shazam');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a navigation bar to always stay at the bottom of the screen regardless of window resizing/size, AND some more content below it scrolling down, you may want to use **vh** attribute (which stands for *view height*) doing something like this:

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:100vh;background:red;">
      <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-self:flex-start;flex-grow:2;">
        //Your upper content
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex;align-self:flex-start;height:80px;">
        //Your nav bar
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:300px;background:gray;">
      //rest of the stuff below
    </div>
```